# How to add multiple git projects to Ctrl-P search path?

Tags: plugin-ctrlp

The main project I work on is split up into multiple git projects. I'd like to be able to Ctrl-P search for files in a different project than the one I'm currently in, but as far as I can tell, I can't make Ctrl-P search anything other than the current git project (since it stops when it finds the .git ancestor).

Is there a way to tell Ctrl-P to search in multiple .git projects?

Comment: Did you [read the doc](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L178)?

Comment: ctrlp-root-markers might help him as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options depending on the layout of directories.

If all these repos are contained in a single root folder that you want to search, then you can search that directory explicitly by running `:CtrlP myproject`. Alternatively, I believe you could say `let g:ctrlp_root_markers=['.root']` and make a .root file in the root (myproject) directory.

If for some strange reason you can't put all these directories in one root, you could make a directory somewhere else, put symlinks in it to all the directories you want searched, put `let g:ctrlp_follow_symlinks=1` in your .vimrc, and explicitly tell CtrlP to use this directory when running (`:CtrlP mynewroot`).

Failing that, you could modify `ctrlp_user_command`, but doing so gets complicated and will ignore other ctrlp settings.

Comment: Thanks `:CtrlP myproject` was what I needed.  Note to anyone else looking at this, `myproject` is the path to the directory that you want to use as your parent.